# 'list index out of range' problem when scraping table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying the **scrape** the table from the wikipedia page
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M

I got the html, found the part containing the table I want:

```
<table class="wikitable sortable">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th>Postcode</th>
   <th>Borough</th>
   <th>Neighbourhood</th>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>M1A</td>
  <td>Not assigned</td>
  <td>Not assigned</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>M2A</td>
  <td>Not assigned</td>
  <td>Not assigned</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>M3A</td>
   <td><a href="/wiki/North_York" title="North York">North York</a></td>
   <td><a href="/wiki/Parkwoods" title="Parkwoods">Parkwoods</a></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>M4A</td>
  <td><a href="/wiki/North_York" title="North York">North York</a></td>
  <td><a href="/wiki/Victoria_Village" title="Victoria Village">Victoria Village</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>M5A</td>
  <td><a href="/wiki/Downtown_Toronto" title="Downtown Toronto">Downtown Toronto</a></td>
  <td><a href="/wiki/Harbourfront_(Toronto)" title="Harbourfront (Toronto)">Harbourfront</a></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
.
.
.
```

I then tried the following:

```
PostalCode=[]
for row in My_table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    PostalCode_cell=row.findAll('td')[0]
    PostalCode.append(PostalCode_cell.text)
    
print(PostalCode)
```

The output is what I have expected:

```
['M1A', 'M2A', 'M3A', 'M4A', 'M5A', 'M5A', 'M6A', 'M6A', 'M7A', 'M8A', 'M9A', 'M1B', 'M1B', 'M2B', 'M3B', 'M4B', 'M4B', 'M5B', 'M5B', 'M6B', ...
```

However, when I want to do the same thing for Borough and Neighbourhood,I always get 'list index out of range'
Here are the codes I used for Borough and Neighbourhood:

```
Borough=[]
for row in My_table.findAll('td') :
    Borough_cell=row.findAll('a')[0]
    Borough.append(Borough_cell.text)
print(Borough)
```

```
Neighbourhood=[]
for row in My_table.findAll('td'):
    Neighbourhood_cell=row.findAll('a')[1]
    Neighbourhood.append(Neighbourhood_cell.text)
print(Neighbourhood)
```

I do notice that in Borough and Neighbourhood there are value "Not Assigned"(which has no 'a'), I do not know if it is these values that cause the problem.
My expected result is to get the table in to pandas format for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the reason is because some postcodes have a link and others don't.

An easier way to do this would be to just grab the `td` for Borough/Neighbourhood and get the text inside:

```
Borough=[]
for row in My_table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    Borough_cell=row.findAll('td')[1]
    Borough.append(Borough_cell.text)
print(Borough)
```

Exactly like you've done for postcodes.

Note that you can now just generalise your code into one for-loop:

```
postcodes = []
boroughs = []
neighbourhoods = []
for row in My_table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    postcodecell, boroughcell, neighbourcell = row.findAll('td')
    postcodes.append(postcodecell.text)
    boroughs.append(boroughcell.text)
    neighbourhoods.append(neighbourcell.text)
```

---

Also, if your project involves lots of Wikipedia pages and lots of scraping/parsing, then I strongly recommend two resources to you:

1. [Wikipedia's API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) with some help [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page).
2. [mwparserfromhell](https://github.com/earwig/mwparserfromhell), a beautiful package that helps parsing a bunch of MediaWiki objects.

Comment: I did as you said, it worked fine for Borough. But when it comes to Neighborhoods, the values I extracted all contained '/n' at the end.   Is there a way to remove it ?

Comment: @Momoxuan Yep, do `neighbourcell.text.rstrip()`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use *[pandas.read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html)* to convert a table directly into a *DataFrame*

```
import pandas as pd
df_list=pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M')
print(df_list[0])
```

Outputs:

```
    Postcode           Borough                                      Neighbourhood
0        M1A      Not assigned                                       Not assigned
1        M2A      Not assigned                                       Not assigned
2        M3A        North York                                          Parkwoods
3        M4A        North York                                   Victoria Village
4        M5A  Downtown Toronto                                       Harbourfront
5        M5A  Downtown Toronto                                        Regent Park
...
[288 rows x 3 columns]
```